# Duplicate key on mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a POS system that will be used to create receipts in two different locations. the problem i am having right now is that when both location enter a receipt at the same time, they would have the same receipt ID, and therefore, i made a pretty bad way to fix this problem.

```
while (!success)
{
    try
    {
        MySqlCommand myCommand4 = new MySqlCommand("Insert into OrderRecords_table values('" + OrderID + "','" + customerCode + "','" + customer + "','" + TelComboBox.Text + "','" + LicenseComboBox.Text + "','" +
              DriverComboBox.Text + "','" + AddressComboBox.Text + "','" + LocationTypeComboBox.Text + "','" + PickupComboBox.Text + "','" + CustomerTypeLabel.Text + "','" +
           Convert.ToDecimal(TotalPriceLabel.Text) + "','" + status + "','" + note + "','" + sandReceiptNo + "','" + createtiming + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "')", myConnection52);
        myCommand4.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (retried == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("收據號碼已改為: " + OrderID);
        }
        success = true;
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        switch (ex.Number)
        {
            case 1062:
                retried = true;
                OrderID = OrderID.Substring(0, 1) + (Convert.ToInt32(OrderID.Substring(1, OrderID.Length - 1)) + 1).ToString("00000");
                success = false;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

i have wrote this to catch the exception, and increase the receipt number when that duplicate key happens, and it worked fine when i first test it, however, it is won't catch the exception anymore, and it would just insert the record.

I don't know how it breaks the rules on mysql.
the situation right now is like the following:
if i have a record with receipt number: m00001 (orderID col)
and the other program is trying to insert a receipt number that is also m00001, it should catch that exception, but it insert both m00001 somehow. (orderID column is set as primary key).

i was doing some researches online to see if there is another way to fix this problem, and i found this

> INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
>     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;

however, this update the old record instead of the new one, is there another way that would update the one that i am trying to insert if it is found duplicated?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really have to handle the primary key yourself? Why not have the database create the appropriate key (with an autoincrement column)? By the way you should look into how to use paramterized queries - what you're doing is prone to injection attacks.

Comment: thanks for the reply @germi is it possible to give me a bit more detail, i am pretty new to this. also, the primary key is the receipt number which i avoid to have the same receipt number on the  database, thats why i made it a primary key column

Comment: Most database systems are able to auto generate a valid primary key on their own so that the developer doesn't have to coordinate multiple inserts himself. Have a look at the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html). About parameterized queries, have a look [at this tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlcsharptutorial/) (first one I found via google, there certainly are others).

Comment: @germi so there is no way to update just the one that i am trying to insert? coz the program is basically done already, its just a little bug that i have to fix, dun wanna change too much from the original

Comment: I don't know that. I never really tried anything like that. But my proposed changes aren't that big, after all. And you wouldn't have to hack something together that the DBMS is offering you for free (and thoroughly tested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic concurrency control problem.  Modern relational databases handle this problem by having the database generate the ID.  Internally, the database utilizes a [mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) to ensure that only one thread is ever able to increment the counter at once.  This is usually exposed in SQL via sequences or a special data type that wraps up the functionality.  In MySQL, there is a special data type called [SERIAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html) that will handle the IDs automatically using MySQL's internal sequence generator called [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Otherwise, you will have to implement locking and concurrency control yourself.  I do not recommend doing this, since MySQL can do it better and faster than you could, but it is possible.

Changing an existing column to begin using AUTO_INCREMENT is a trivial operation that can be quickly done against smaller data sets (less than a million rows or so).  Let's say you have a table that looks like this:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE t_receipts;
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table      | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                            |
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| t_receipts | CREATE TABLE `t_receipts` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `amount` double(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Converting the table is as simple as:

```
ALTER TABLE t_receipts CHANGE id id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Or, using the SERIAL shortcut:

```
ALTER TABLE t_receipts CHANGE id id SERIAL;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @diz, but i would like to have my own unique receipt id like M00001 to M99999 and C00001 to C99999 does auto increment works?

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT only works for numeric values.  If you want your receipt ID to contain non-numeric characters, I would recommend one of two things: (1) implementing a custom receipt-id-to-database-id mapping or (2) adding an additional UNIQUE column in which you insert your special receipt IDs, generated by a separate ID generating service that implements locking outside of the database.  Auto-incrementing numeric primary keys are necessary for proper database design in the majority of cases (excepting some edge cases, of course), so you should use one no matter what you decide.

Comment: To expand upon the mapping -- I previously implemented such a mapping when developing an OLTP system.  The order IDs provided to customers contained primary key IDs of the corresponding database records, but were encoded by a method on the ORM class implementing that table.  Encoding IDs in this manner has the advantage of obscuring information about your volume of business.

Comment: thanks for all the answers, but does anyone know why it is not catching the exception? because i am sure that it did catch it first time i try it, but it just allow to insert when the primary key already existed in the table right now.

Comment: It's possible the code is throwing other exceptions that you're not catching.  When trapping code, you should be sure to catch all possible exceptions.  If you don't want to catch all possible exceptions, you should only trap the code that throws the exception you're interested in.  Try trapping all exceptions or changing your try block to wrap only the ExecuteNonQuery method call.  I would also add a default block in your switch statement so that you're properly handling other database exceptions, which could also be the case.

Answer (score -1):

visual studio has a great tool called entity framework for .net, there is a [guide to use it with MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html). It will make everything a lot safer and easier, it would suggest you use this.

Using the entity Framework and Linq if there is a problem, like a duplicate key it will always throw an exception. Creating keys if you cannot use auto increment or a GUID is a bit easier because of the exceptions, you will always know when the key you tried to insert is wrong.

A table in your database will just be a class in C# with the entity model, you simply create a new object of this class fill in the field, add it to the collection (which corresponds to the records in your database) and save. on save it will check if it is original and the record will be created.

For as far as I know this will never allow for a duplicate key no matter how many connections and how simultaneous the records are added.

example code for adding with linq to your entity model:

```
MyDbEntities mydb = new MyDbEntities();
Order order = new Order();
order.OrderID = "m0000001";
try
{
    mydb.Order.Add(order);
    mydb.SaveChange();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    if(excpetion == duplicate key) // pseudo code, don't know the error for duplicate keys
    {
        order.OrderID = m0000002;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried to use linq before, but it didnt work well, and i switched to mysqlcommand and such, it sounds like it would work well, but the program is basically done with this only bug right now, and i don't really wanna change all my connections and commands and needed to test everything agian.

Comment: That i can understand, i had some problems with entity framework and linq my self in the beginning but now i know how to use it I'm very pleased. but keep it in mind for next time then ;) it's really worth it.

Comment: thanks alot for that, but do you know why it is not catching the duplicate exception in my case?

Comment: No, not from the code provided, I think the problem is server sided. no exception is thrown at all? everything works properly you just end up with 2 exactly the same ID's in your table? this would indicate mysql has made a mistake or something is not properly set, else a duplicate key could never occur in the database.